How to know where's the Linux instance is hosted?
How to know where's the Linux instance is hosted?
I have several instances of Linux and all of them hosted either by datacenter (CloudFlare for example and other) or self-hosted. I want to know if there's an instrument to get datacenter info by IP address except whois. (These instances is not mine, but I have access to them. The goal is run script at the dozens of instances and get information about where's that works.)
The first way I've tried is getting info by whois, but it has no always data about org-name.

What do you mean by "hosted"? Are you trying to identify if it's on a cloud environment? Whether the DNS records are with a particular DNS service (since you mention whois)? Whether the domain is registered with some particular registrar?

If those are your instances, just query your cloud provider for the IPs and match them. I don't know about CloudFlare, but it would be easy to do so using aws or gcloud utilities for AWS and GCP respective.

If not, you can also check if your cloud of choice publishes IP ranges somewhere, and then check against those.

If you can run a script on them, then see: Detect whether a Linux execution host is cloud based or not

So the only way that's There is no standard mechanism by which cloud vendors inject identification into running virtual machines. and tries automating that is unsuccessful for now.

There's still the other option of checking if your cloud provider publishes IP addresses it owns (e.g. https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/ips/, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ip-ranges.html)

But otherwise, I'd expect it to be intentionally hard as matter of security (by obscurity, but security nonetheless) - if you own the system, there are legitimate ways to find out, if you don't then I suppose it wouldn't be different from if you were a hacker
